# Custom module AJAX 403 for anonymous user

Tags: ajax, drupal, permissions

I have a module with a list of pages that it accesses via AJAX for different tasks

```
/spower
/spower-geometry
...
```

. I'm trying to create a single permission that will allow the anonymous user to access everything. If I'm logged in as administrator, everything works the way it's supposed to. However, the anonymous user gets a 403 error. Do I need a different permission hook for each path? This is what I have so far:

```
function spower_permission() {
  return array(
    'access intro page' => array(
    'title' => t('Access Intro page'),
    'description' => t('Allow anonymous users to access spower intro page'),
  ),
  'access SparkerPower app' => array(
    'title' => t('Access full page'),
    'description' => t('Allow users to access full spower app'),
   ),
 );
}

function spower_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['spower'] = array(
      'title' => t('SparkerPOWER'),
      'page callback' => 'spower_form',
      'access arguments' => array('access SparkerPower app'),
      'description' => t('form for SparkerPOWER. Enter your house information, and learn how solar panels can help you.'),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    $items['spower_geometry/%'] = array( //send data from Jquery (map areas)
      'title' => 'Ajax callback',
      'description' => 'Callback for jQuery area AJAX request.',
      'page callback' => 'spower_geometry_callback',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
      'access arguments' => array('access spower geometry'),
      'access callback' => 'user_access',
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a different hook for each path defined in your `HOOK_MENU`. Your code is correct by using the `access arguments`. You don't need to specify the `access callback` in your second menu item.

Did you also updated the permissions in backend so the anonymous users can access your defined menu paths ? It is under `admin/people/permissions`.

Comment: I did. the 'access SparkerPower app' option is set for all users, but the 'access intro page' doesn't 'stick' when I save permissions - when I click save, the checkboxes revert to empty.

Comment: That is strange ... do you have any errors/warnings when looking at the logs (recent logs)? Do you have access as anonymous user after updating the permissions for 'access SparkerPower app'?

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing `access arguments` to `TRUE`, which didn't work. I then changed `access arguments` to `array('access SparkerPower app')`, the one I had defined earlier. That worked, and I was able to access all the url paths I needed to with the anonymous user.

Comment: Glad it works now, even if code hasn't changed. If you want to bypass the permissions on a menu item, you can use 'access callback' => true (without 'access arguments')